# SSL wildcard certificate - multiple subdomains and multiple tiers

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain

I have the following requirement to map many domains to a single site instance for my web application, and I'm wondering if this is solvable using a single SSL wildcard certificate in IIS 7, or whether I need two wildcard cerfiticates.  Here's my current plan:

```
Certificate #1 - *.mydomain.com
https://customer1.mydomain.com
https://customer2.mydomain.com
https://customer2.mydomain.com
etc...

Certificate #2 - admin.*.mydomain.com
https://admin.customer1.mydomain.com
https://admin.customer2.mydomain.com
https://admin.customer3.mydomain.com
etc...
```

My intentions are the following:

1. A single IP address that all of the above domains map to.
2. Can this be accomplished without the second certificate? I was told that I must have two by both Thawte and Godaddy.
3. The website is really the same site instance for all clients, but a different color scheme and logos will be displayed based on the URL. (hence multiple domain names)
4. I do not want to have to replace the certificate each time I add a new customer, hence the wildcard certificate.
5. I want to automatically redirect any request that comes in as http:// or blank to any of the above URLs to its https:// counterpart.  For example, http://customer1.mydomain.com would automatically redirect the user to https://customer1.mydomain.com.  I am currently doing this with a regular certificate, but since we're growing, I want to switch to wildcard.  Is this still possible with the URL Rewrite IIS Snap-In?

I'm curious if anything I'm doing here is bad practice or if there is a better approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this posting, this is not possible with a wildcard certificate.

Comment: Is this possible now? I need to configure wildcard ssl for a system that works similar to yours.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, certificate #2 isn't possible.  However, certificate #1 is.  To use a single wildcard, you might be better off using certificate #1, and then using customer1.mydomain.com/admin for the admin portion.  Or admin.mydomain.com/customer1.  Then you could configure your DNS, http redirects, and context switching to get the client to right portion of your app from the admin.customer1.mydomain.com.

Another option would be to use names like customer1.mydomain.com and customer1admin.mydomain.com.  That would all fall under your certificate #1 wildcard and get a similar outcome to your plan perhaps.